# Youtube video not autoplaying on React-modal-video

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming

I'm using react-modal-video in my React project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-video?activeTab=readme

I've enable autoplay for the Youtube video. But it isn't working:

```
<ModalVideo channel="youtube" youtube={{ autoplay: 1 }} isOpen={isOpen} videoId="<video_id>" onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
```

Setting the `autoplay: 1` should autoplay the video when opened. Why isn't it working?

**Note:** The README in the above link is wrong. I had to go through the package to see the ModalVideo implementation. I may add it here if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

set mute also  1 like this

```rb
<ModalVideo channel="youtube" youtube={{ autoplay: 1,mute:1 }} isOpen={isOpen} videoId="<video_id>" onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/appleple/react-modal-video/issues/16

from gusblacknails:

> I've figured out why it's not working anymore. There's no need to hack the library just set mute:1.
> It is a problem with Youtube's API, you can't autoplay without muting the sound at the same time.
> So setting the ModalVideo props like that will do the trick:

```
<ModalVideo
            channel="youtube"
            youtube={{
              autoplay: 1,
              mute: 1
            }}
          ...
          />
```

This is really silly so I just used the official embeded script from youtube.